# How to make a calendar

Tags: css, html

[image]

As a homework assignment, I need to recreate this screenshot with pure code. I currently got stuck with making the calendar. When I tried to make mine for some reason I can't get the numerical days under the day itself. As you can see there are seven days in a row but 8 numerical days in a row. How could I fix this
[image]
[image]

What changes do I need to make on my code to fix it
This is the HTML code:

```
<h2>Calendar</h2>

<p class="october">October 2017</p>
<ul class="weekdays">
  <li>M</li>
  <li>T</li>
  <li>W</li>
  <li>T</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>S</li>
  <li>S</li>
</ul>

<ul class="days">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li><span class="active">10</span></li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>22</li>
  <li>23</li>
  <li>24</li>
  <li>25</li>
  <li>26</li>
  <li>27</li>
  <li>28</li>
  <li>29</li>
  <li>30</li>
  <li>31</li>
</ul>
```

And my CSS code:

```
/* Calendar */
.october{
  text-align: center;
}
.weekdays {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    text-align: center;
}

.weekdays li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}

.days {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 0;
}

.days li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size:12px;
    color: #777;
}

.days li .active {
    color: #3c8cd7 !important
}
```

P.S. I'm not completely done with everything else that's why it still looks sloppy

Comment: you have not told us what you are having issues with. [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question

Comment: [Try this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_calendar.asp)

Comment: Your li's are too narrow. 10% width = 10 per row, when you want 7. The ideal width is 14.2857% (100/7), BUT, whitespace between inline block elements will add to the width of each item, so you will need to go narrower. I expect that is why in the example @DhavalJardosh posted above the width of li's is 13.6%. I should point out that there are methods for removing whitespace between inline-block elements, which you might want to research rather than guestimate a width that works.

Comment: The calendar looks like a table, right? The days are positioned in columns to have a relation to the weekday, right? Each week is in a row, rigth? So may I ask: Why don‘t you use a html `<table>` to have a semantically correct calendar table? What is the benefit of a `<ul>` list here? Just some thoughts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purposes you could use an [html table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) like so:

See live: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/airbridge/pen/xPPgNK)

This will solve the placement issues of the numbers and align them with the days. Ill leave the color styling to you since its not what you stated was your problem.

```html
 <table>
    <tr>
    <th>M</th>
    <th>T</th>
    <th>W</th>
    <th>T</th>
    <th>F</th>
    <th>S</th>
    <th>S</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27<br></td>
    <td>28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yep, this is the way to go. Tables are usually discouraged (and rightly so), but for something like a calendar, which has an inherent row-and-column structure and really wouldn't make sense laid out differently, a table is the best choice. By the way, you can put your example code in a snippet so that it renders inside your answer.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Thanks ! Hadn't used the snippet feature before in an answer

Answer (score 2):

You can try thi. it will show you a nice result of the calondar, play with css to have the exact one in the picture..

All what is inside  separate it in the css file..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
ul {list-style-type: none;}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}

.month {
    padding: 70px 25px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #1abc9c;
    text-align: center;
}

.month ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.month ul li {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.month .prev {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.month .next {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.weekdays {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.weekdays li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13.6%;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
}

.days {
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 0;
}

.days li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13.6%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size:12px;
    color: #777;
}

.days li .active {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #1abc9c;
    color: white !important
}

/* Add media queries for smaller screens */
@media screen and (max-width:720px) {
    .weekdays li, .days li {width: 13.1%;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    .weekdays li, .days li {width: 12.5%;}
    .days li .active {padding: 2px;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 290px) {
    .weekdays li, .days li {width: 12.2%;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>CSS Calendar</h1>

<div class="month">      
  <ul>
    <li class="prev">&#10094;</li>
    <li class="next">&#10095;</li>
    <li>
      August<br>
      <span style="font-size:18px">2017</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="weekdays">
  <li>Mo</li>
  <li>Tu</li>
  <li>We</li>
  <li>Th</li>
  <li>Fr</li>
  <li>Sa</li>
  <li>Su</li>
</ul>

<ul class="days">  
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li><span class="active">10</span></li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>22</li>
  <li>23</li>
  <li>24</li>
  <li>25</li>
  <li>26</li>
  <li>27</li>
  <li>28</li>
  <li>29</li>
  <li>30</li>
  <li>31</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```